# Which bands are considered significant in the fingerprint region of IR spectra?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, ir-spectroscopy

I'm currently writing my characterisations for the experimental section of my dissertation and can't decide which peaks from the fingerprint region of my IR are worth reporting. Is there a threshold of %Trasmittance, anything below which is considered not to be significant? For example, I know that a strong band covers most of the y axis, a medium about a half and a weak about a third. Therefore, is it worth reporting very weak bands with only 10-15 %Transmission?

Comment: There isn't a good answer to this. It depends. For instance the "weak" bands might be due to a low concentration of an important impurity.

Comment: My compounds should be pretty much pure. They are usually columned, dried on hi-vac and in a desiccator, before any characterisation. NMR is clean, solvent and water-free, only one spot on TLC.

Comment: Fingerprint is important as a whole.  That is why it is called like that.  Normally you report significant bands only. Like OH if an alcohol was a target

Comment: Unless your dissertation is something else than organic synthesis.  But given the question it shouldn't be the case.

Comment: It's basically inorganic catalysts, but for organic reactions, so my products are organic :D